# What are the differences between strings 'True','False' and boolean True,False in Python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

```
sorted_varieties = price_extremes.sort_values(by =['min','max'], ascending = ['False','False'])
```

| variety | min | max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pinot Grigio | 4.0 | 70.0 |
| Malbec-Syrah | 4.0 | 78.0 |
| White Blend | 4.0 | 375.0 |
| Tempranillo | 4.0 | 600.0 |

```
sorted_varieties = price_extremes.sort_values(by =['min','max'], ascending = [False,False])
```

| variety | min | max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ramisco | 495.0 | 495.0 |
| Terrantez | 236.0 | 236.0 |
| Francisa | 160.0 | 160.0 |
| Rosenmuskateller | 150.0 | 150.0 |

I got two different sorted values when I passed the ascending arguments in the list format of booleans in string and boolean formats. I expected to run into an error if I passed Boolean values as strings. But the code got executed without any error. How do the booleans in string `'True','False'` differ from boolean `True, False` values in execution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non-empty string evaluates as `True`, so in your case it is similar to running:

```
sorted_varieties = price_extremes.sort_values(by=['min','max'],
                                              ascending=[True, True])
```